How to run "adb shell bugreportz" and get bug report programatically in android
I have to get the bug report and upload from my android device to server. I can get the bug report by manually running adb command "adb shell bugreportz". However I am trying to get the report programmatically I have tried below code
public static String executeBugreportz() {
        try {
            Log.d(
                    "BugReport"
                    ,
                    "Bug report triggered"
            );
            // Execute the adb shell command
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell bugreportz");

            // Get the input stream to read the output from the executed command
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            // Wait for the command to finish executing
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();

            // Return the output if the execution was successful
            if (exitCode == 0) {
                Log.d(
                        "BugReport"
                        ,
                        "Bug report generated successfully"
                );
                return output.toString();
            } else {
                Log.d(
                        "BugReport"
                        ,
                        "Failed to execute adb shell bugreportz"
                );
                return "Failed to execute adb shell bugreportz";
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(
                    "BugReport"
                    ,
                    "Exception occurred while executing adb shell bugreportz:" + e.getMessage()
            );
            return "Exception occurred while executing adb shell bugreportz: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

This code didn't work for me. Please let me know how can I achieve this if someone has explored this part.

"This code didn't work for me" is a bad error description. Please describe what happens and what are your specific problems or errors you have to solve.

The error which I am getting while reading at reader.readLine() is  FAIL:Failed to connect to dumpstatez service: No such file or directory

What Android device do you use for testing? BTW: Executing bugreportz will not output anything on stdout or stderr.

I am using moto g34 android device with android 14 in it.

I am able to generate the report programatically using DevicePolicyManager as follows without running the adb command. The above approach by running the command using runtime worked for system apps.
    private fun requestBugReport(context: Context) {
            val dpm = context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
            val componentName = ComponentName(context, SampleReceiver::class.java)
            val result = dpm.requestBugreport(componentName);
    }

